# share image to inastagram from own android application

Tags: android, instagram

i m trying to share the image from my android application to instagram application.........  i cant upload the image.........

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Map<String, String> doUpload() {
Log.i(TAG, "Upload");
Long timeInMilliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
String timeInSeconds = timeInMilliseconds.toString();
MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new     
MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
Map returnMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
// check for cookies
/*  if( httpClient.getCookieStore() == null ) {
 returnMap.put("result", "Not logged in");
        return returnMap;
    }*/

    try {
        // create multipart data
         System.out.println("image path name : "+processedImageUri.getPath());
         System.out.println("image file path : "+ImgFilePath);
        File imageFile = new File(ImgFilePath);//processedImageUri.getPath());
        FileBody partFile = new FileBody(imageFile);
        StringBody partTime = new StringBody(timeInSeconds);

        multipartEntity.addPart("photo", partFile );
        multipartEntity.addPart("device_timestamp", partTime);
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        Log.e(TAG,"Error creating mulitpart form: " + e.toString());
        returnMap.put("result", "Error creating mulitpart form: " + e.toString());
        return returnMap;
    }

    // upload
    try {
        System.out.println("111111111111111111");
        System.out.println("multipart entity value : "+multipartEntity.toString());
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(Utils.UPLOAD_URL);
        httpPost.setEntity(multipartEntity);
        System.out.println("http post vlaue : "+httpPost.toString());
        System.out.println("http client value : "+httpClient.toString());
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        System.out.println("Http response value : "+httpResponse.toString());
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        Log.i(TAG, "Upload status: " + httpResponse.getStatusLine());
        System.out.println("staus entity value : "+httpResponse.getStatusLine().toString());
        System.out.println("http status : "+HttpStatus.SC_OK);

        // test result code
        if( httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.SC_OK ) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Login HTTP status fail: " + httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            returnMap.put("result", "HTTP status error: " + httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() );
            return returnMap;
        }

        // test json response
        // should look like
        /*
        {"status": "ok"}
        */
        if( httpEntity != null ) {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpEntity.getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            String json = reader.readLine();
            System.out.println("Entity value : "+json);
            JSONTokener jsonTokener = new JSONTokener(json);
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonTokener);
            Log.i(TAG,"JSON: " + jsonObject.toString());

            String loginStatus = jsonObject.getString("status");

            if( !loginStatus.equals("ok") ) {
                Log.e(TAG, "JSON status not ok: " + jsonObject.getString("status"));
                returnMap.put("result", "JSON status not ok: " + jsonObject.getString("status") );
                return returnMap;
            }
        }
    } catch( Exception e ) {
        Log.e(TAG, "HttpPost exception: " + e.toString());
        returnMap.put("result", "HttpPost exception: " + e.toString());
        return returnMap;
    }

    // configure / comment
    try {
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(Utils.CONFIGURE_URL);
        String partComment = txtCaption.getText().toString();
        List<NameValuePair> postParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("device_timestamp", timeInSeconds));
        postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("caption", partComment));
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParams, HTTP.UTF_8));
        System.out.println("http client value : "+httpClient.toString());
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        // test result code
        if( httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.SC_OK ) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Upload comment fail: " + httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            returnMap.put("result", "Upload comment fail: " + httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() );
            return returnMap;
        }

        returnMap.put("result", "ok");
        return returnMap;
    } catch( Exception e ) {
        Log.e(TAG, "HttpPost comment error: " + e.toString());
        returnMap.put("result", "HttpPost comment error: " + e.toString());
        return returnMap;
    }
```

the above is the code which i m using for upload the image and the url for this is UPLOAD_URL = "http://instagr.am/api/v1/media/upload/" .............
pls can anyone help me to upload the image to instagram....... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

The Instagram API doesn't support uploading yet.

From the Instagram API Docs:

> **At this time, uploading via the API is not possible. We made a conscious choice not to add this for the following reasons:**
>
> Instagram is about your life on the go – we hope to encourage photos
>   from within the app. However, in the future we may give whitelist
>   access to individual apps on a case by case basis. We want to fight
>   spam & low quality photos. Once we allow uploading from other sources,
>   it's harder to control what comes into the Instagram ecosystem. All
>   this being said, we're working on ways to ensure users have a
>   consistent and high-quality experience on our platform.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any other possible way to share my images into instagram.