# Intent for sending Instagram direct message

Tags: java, android, android-intent, instagram

I want people to be able to send a direct message to my Instagram account from my android application.
What is the intent for sending a direct message on Instagram?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code

```
String type = "video/*";
String filename = "/myVideo.mp4";
String mediaPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + filename;

createInstagramIntent(type, mediaPath);

private void createInstagramIntent(String type, String mediaPath){

    // Create the new Intent using the 'Send' action.
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    // Set the MIME type
    share.setType(type);

    // Create the URI from the media
    File media = new File(mediaPath);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(media);

    // Add the URI to the Intent.
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, [URI of photo]);
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, [Text of caption]);

    // Broadcast the Intent.
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share to"));
}
```

See [official documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/android-intents/)

**See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15002468/instagram-from-android-open-on-certain-user-and-add-caption-to-uploaded-image) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15002468/instagram-from-android-open-on-certain-user-and-add-caption-to-uploaded-image/24663170#24663170) also**

Answer (score 0):

To Share plain text to the Instagram DM(Direct) use following:

```
val shareIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Assd") // set uri
shareIntent.setPackage("com.instagram.android")
startActivity(shareIntent)
```

Or You Also can use a file instead:

```
String type = "video/*";
...
intent..putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, [URI of photo]);
```